# how I can print psk only?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I want to print psk & it's value (i.e. password)
I tries this:

```
sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/My SSID | grep psk | cut -f2 -d =
```

but I got this :

```
wpa-psk
```

```
mypassword
```

I want to print :

```
mypassword
```

only

Which command will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -oP "^psk=\K.*" /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/yourssid
```